# Referring to a variable based on user input

Tags: ruby, user-input

With the following code, I expect the user enters `"pluto"` or `"scooby"`, and that instance's `speak()` method to be called.

```
class Dog
  def speak()
    puts "Woof"
  end
end

scooby = Dog.new
pluto = Dog.new

puts "Which dog would you like to speak? [scooby/pluto]"
response = gets.chomp
response.speak()
```

It would be beyond awesome if you could tell me how to do this, and/or what to call this.

Comment: Regarding "what you call this" it depends on whether you really _want_ to call `speak` through the variable name you computed indirectly (generally frowned upon) or whether you just call the method through an object that you looked up by name.  I don't think either situation has a programming or design pattern named for it, but would be interested if answers pop up that know whether ones exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Ruby programmers would recommend that you not try to look up global variables by name, but rather store your dogs in a `Hash` indexed by name.

So you should have:

```
kennel = {}
kennel['scooby'] = Dog.new    
kennel['pluto'] = Dog.new
```

Then you can say

```
kennel[response].speak
```

Of course, you'd probably want to guard against the value of `response` not being the name of a dog in the kennel; I'll leave that research for you. :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't consider using a Hash - so I'd also be able to populate that hash with user input, and allow the user to reference objects they created themselves? Awesome!

Comment: Yes, in your application, the hash will be populated with user input: input a dog's name, then say `kennel[name] = Dog.new`, etc.  Later your dogs might have additional properties, and you can even store their names as properties, too.  I doubt there is a name for this pattern; it's just a normal use of a hashmap.  You store stuff, look things up by key, then operate on the item you found.  If you accessed  obejcts via global variable name there _might_ be a pattern name there; I just don't know what it is.  "Dynamic variable lookup", maybe?

Comment: Thanks Ray - I'm going to start researching "Dynamic variable lookup" now :D

As to making sure that the requested Dog is in the kennel[],
I know how to do that :

    if(kennel.key?(response))
      kennel[response].speak
    else
      puts "What are you smoking? That dog doesn't exist."
    end

I really appreciate your input guys, it goes a very long way

Answer (score 0):

You can `eval` the user's input to get the value of a local variable:

```
eval(response).speak()
```

but, it's not safe.

An additional check is:

```
eval(response).speak() if local_variables.include?(response.to_sym)
```

but it's not safe either.

Comment: I haven't really touched on eval yet, so I don't know a whole lot about it - when you say "It's not safe," I'm not sure I understand... Is this an input you would want to sanitize prior to calling eval on it, similar to php's $input = stripslashes($user_input); ?

Comment: I mean, that user's input should not never be eval'ed, even if sanitized.